# curl command can't be found, OSX utilities have been replaced by GNU coreutils... how to start from scratch?

Tags: macos, terminal, install, command-line, homebrew

I recently installed homebrew and I was having a hard time because I could not install it as curl command couldn't be found, someone pointed me to use wget and that worked to install homebrew but now I am trying to figure out how to get the curl command back.  I was patching an android rom with openpdroid and ran into a problem and in the process I found out when working out the error with the developer of autopatcher that I somehow or another the bundled OSX/BSD utils were replaced with GNU coreutils.  I have no idea if the osx/bsdutils or GNU coreutils have anything to do with curl.

I tried

```
$ brew install curl
==> Installing curl dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pkg-config-0.28.mountain_lion.bo
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.28.tar.gz
Error: /usr/bin/curl is not executable
```

Keep in mind that I like a toddler just learning my first words when it comes to working with the terminal shell.

also so you know

```
$ curl --version
-bash: curl: command not found
```

Is there a way to get back to having OSX bundled utilities as default if that is what I need to install curl.

Comment: It's possible that Homebrew has simply modified your PATH variable to point to its binaries instead of the built-in utilities. Can you post the content of your PATH variable (`echo $PATH`?)

Comment: $ echo $PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/lo‌​cal/git/bin

Comment: The curl command was lost prior to having homebrew installed at which time I used wget.

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/curl` return?

Comment: `$ ls -l /usr/bin/curl` `lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 21 Sep 23 23:57 /usr/bin/curl -> /usr/bin/curl.wrapper`

Comment: Is `curl.wrapper` a shell script (`file /usr/bin/curl.wrapper`)? And what does `ls -l /usr/bin/curl*` return?

Comment: `file /usr/bin/curl.wrapper` --> `/usr/bin/curl.wrapper: cannot open` `/usr/bin/curl.wrapper' (No such file or directory)`

Comment: $ `ls -l /usr/bin/curl*`  -->
`lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel     21 Sep 23 14:57 /usr/bin/curl -> /usr/bin/curl.wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   3759 Jan 28  2013 /usr/bin/curl-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 139056 Sep 23 14:55 /usr/bin/curl.bin`

Comment: Ok so I can use `/usr/bin/curl.bin`  my question now is why do I need the curl.bin rather just curl

Answer (score 3):

Something seems to have changed your `curl` binary. To fix it, run

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/curl-wrapper
sudo mv /usr/bin/curl.bin /usr/bin/curl
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your path -- homebrew often instructs you to modify path and installs into `usr/local/bin`. The default curl executable is `/usr/bin/curl`.   Or try running it as `/usr/bin/curl`

**Edit**:
Another thing to try. Do you have xcode installed?  You can go into Xcode Preferences->Downloads->Components and install the command line tools for xcode which I *think* should include your original curl executable.

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: The curl command was lost prior to having homebrew installed at which time I used wget.

Comment: @user2821160 see update to answer